# Загрузка данных с парсера на питоне в БД mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, загрузка, обработка-данных

Я сделал парсер страницы. У меня есть данные, которые я смог выгрузить. Они хранятся у меня в excel файле, но мне требуется загрузить эти данные в БД.
Не могу найти толковых уроков по тому, как это можно сделать с Python.
То есть полученные данные в питон сгружать в БД mySQL.
Если есть полезные ссылки на уроки, скиньте пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: используйте любой драйвер для этого, их несколько штук

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь Pandas + SQL Alchemy:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_conn_str = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_conn_str)

(pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx')
   .to_sql('table_name', conn, index=False))
```

PS кстати [Pandas умеет парсить HTML таблицы](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)